# Spring Boot , Security регистрация с помощью JPA

Tags: spring, безопасность, jpa, boot

У меня настроена проверка пользователей которые залиты "в ручную" и она работает  используя InMemoryUserDetailsManager.
ВОТ ....

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
     @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        }




        @Bean
        @Override
        protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService()  {
           UserDetails user =
                    User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                            .username("admin")
                            .password("admin")
                            .roles("USER")
                            .build();
            UserDetails user_root =
                    User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                            .username("root")
                            .password("root")
                            .roles("ROOT")
                            .build();
return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user,user_root);//<---- надо заменить пользователь на реальные из ДБ

        }
}
```

Еще у меня настроено JPA 
и существует следующая  антити

```
@Entity
@Table(name="loginfull")
public class Users {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Long ID;

@Column(name="user_name")
   private String User;

    @Column(name="user_pass")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="user_roll")
    private String Roll;


    public Long getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(Long ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return User;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        User = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRoll() {
        return Roll;
    }

    public void setRoll(String roll) {
        Roll = roll;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Users{" + "ID=" + ID + ", User='" + User + '\'' + ", password='" + password + '\'' + ", Roll='" + Roll + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

и так вопрос таков - Как подружить перечисленное ( можно даже заменить  InMemoryUserDetailsManager , главное всё работало ). Если возможно в ответ добавьте код ( коментов по больше )

Answer (score 0):

Аутентификацией пользователей занимается `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, который для получения контекста пользователя из прикладного приложения в понятной ему терминологии использует адаптер `UserDetailsService`. В вашем случае это его наследник `InMemotyUserDetailsManager`. Все, что необходимо сделать, это реализовать свой адаптер и разместить его бин в контексте вместо `InMemotyUserDetailsManager`. Простейший пример выглядит так

```java
@Service
public class UserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    // CRUD-репозиторий для доступа к пользовательским данным
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByUser(username);
        if( user == null )
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);

        return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
                .builder()
                .username(user.getUser())
                .password(user.getPassword())
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
    }

}
```